# How to group list elements according to groups defined in a grouping vector?

Tags: r, list, grouping

Consider a list and a grouping vector

```r
l = list(3:4, 8:10, 7:8)
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 4
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  8  9 10
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] 7 8

g = c("A", "B", "A")
```

What is the easiest way to group `l` elements according to groups defined in `g`, such that we get:

```r
l_expected = list(c(3:4, 7:8), 8:10))
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 4 7 8
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use `tapply` + `unlist`, and `unname` if necessary.

```r
tapply(l, g, unlist)
```

output

```r
$A
[1] 3 4 7 8

$B
[1]  8  9 10
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `split`

```
lapply(split(l, g), unlist)
$A
[1] 3 4 7 8

$B
[1]  8  9 10
```

---

Or get the `lengths` and `split` after `unlist`ing

```
 split(unlist(l), rep(g, lengths(l)))
$A
[1] 3 4 7 8

$B
[1]  8  9 10
```